# SilverLight Overlay HTML?

Tags: silverlight, dhtml

I'm looking to build a flyout type menu in Silverlight that will be added to an aspx page. the items will be built dynamically via data returned from a web service. All of the samples on building menues do not allow the silverlight to "flyout" over the HTML. Can this be accomplished? If so, what would be the best method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you:

1. Set your silverlight windowless property to true
2. Set silveright background to transparent.
3. Use CSS to position your object tag so that it lays on top of other HTML elements.

Comment: Depending on your definition of dramatic and details of your app, I would have to say either "yes" or "a little"

Comment: This would be a replacement menu for SharePoint, so given the overhead that SharePoint already puts on the app I don't think that SilverLight will be our answer. But, your answer appears to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of the other-way-round, but maybe this could be of use?

[How to embed HTML inside a Visual WebGui Silverlight application](http://weblogs.asp.net/visualwebgui/archive/2008/07/31/how-to-embed-html-inside-a-visual-webgui-silverlight-application.aspx)